# Master page nightmares

Tags: master-page, sharepoint-server

I cannot find any solution to the problem I am having so far. I hope someone can help me.

I have a site collection with a custom master page. When I edit it (change the default css file used) I am getting a "Code blocks are not allowed in this file." error when opening a document set in a document library. The rest of the site (collection) works fine.

Not a problem, I though. I just roll back the change, and restore the previous version of the master page. Publish, approve, etc., but guess what? The error remains. Fortunately, I still had another copy present of the master page which was already on the system since we first created our custom master page. I selected this one as master page on the site collection, problem solve.

Now I got curious....what if I make a copy of the master page currently selected - the one that gives no errors - and upload it under a different name.
So master page xyz.master was giving no errors:
1. copy it
2. rename it to abc.master
3. let the site collection use this "new" master page.

Guess what? Errors again! So I am using an identical master page here, an exact copy of the master page that works fine, but still I am getting errors.

Has anyone a clue what's going on here?

Thanks so much for your answer.

Regards,
Rob

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075514/code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

looks like your directly inserting javascript (inline scripting),, dont think its on the masterpage but rather the layouts page that both masterpages reference!

dont worry... ive done it when adding some inline script to layouts page and it throws this error:

solution:

goto web application web.config file.... open up in word document and look for:

```
<PageParserPath
```

change `AllowServerSideScript="false"` to `AllowServerSideScript="true"` and should work fine!